# "error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1" installing geonode. Help me

Tags: github, failed-installation, ubuntu-13.10

I was installing GeoNode on ubuntu 13.10 in developers mode according to git:[GeoNode](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/)
I encountered the error `error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`
on issuing command: `pip install -e geonode --use-mirrors --allow-external pyproj --allow-unverified pyproj`

Instruction:

```
  # retrieve latest apt-get list
sudo apt-get update

# Essential build tools and libraries
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

# Python native dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev python-imaging python-lxml python-pyproj python-shapely python-nose python-httplib2 python-pip python-software-properties

# Setup virtualenv tools
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper

# Java dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes openjdk-6-jdk ant maven2 --no-install-recommends

# Supporting tools
sudo apt-get install -y  git gettext

# Node and tools required for static development
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo npm install -y -g bower
sudo npm install -y -g grunt-cli

# Add virtualenvwrapper to your environment
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
export WORKON_HOME=~/.venvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=$HOME/.pip-downloads

# Setup a virtualenv for geonode
mkvirtualenv geonode
workon geonode

# Clone GeoNode
git clone https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode.git

# Install GeoNode in the local virtualenv
# In pip 1.5 pyproj needs to be whitelisted
pip install -e geonode --use-mirrors --allow-external pyproj --allow-unverified pyproj
cd geonode

# Compile GeoServer
paver setup

# Start the development servers
paver start

# Visit the development geonode site
http://localhost:8000
```

and
ERROR is

```
   i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/home/ubuntuuser/.venvs/geonode/build/lxml/src/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w

i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/lxml/etree.so

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/ubuntuuser/.venvs/geonode/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=u'/home/ubuntuuser/.venvs/geonode/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Zfd7q4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ubuntuuser/.venvs/geonode/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/ubuntuuser/.venvs/geonode/build/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntuuser/.pip/pip.log
(geonode)ubuntuuser@ubuntuuser-HP-Pavilion-dv4-Notebook-PC:~$
```